# Time duration in HTML

Tags: html, field

Is there any sophisticated way of accepting time-duration in HTML? I tried to use `input` anchor with `type = "time"` but I could only accept 24 hours.

Comment: what kind of format you want?

Comment: I want to accept the number of hours. e.g. number of hours - 06:30 (6 hours 30 minutes), 40:45 (40 hours 45 minutes )

Answer (score 0):

HTML has no native features for accepting durations as user input.

If you want anything more complex than a plain text input, you will need to write JavaScript to do it (or find a prewritten library that serves your purposes).

Answer (score 0):

The HTML transition-duration property specifies how many seconds (s) or milliseconds (ms) a transition effect takes to complete.